# Is there a way to do a different query if checkbox is unchecked

Tags: php, html, sql, post, checkbox

Here is what I have so far. My issue is with the if statement.

```
echo "<div>
        <input type='checkbox' id='retired' name='retired' checked>
        <label for='retired'>Hide Retired Systems</label>
      </div>";
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM db WHERE `Physical Location` != "RETIRED"';
$sql_all = 'SELECT * FROM db';

if (checkbox retired = True):
   showDBtable($sql);
else:
   showDBtable($sql_all);
```

I understand I should be using JavaScript but is there any way to do this via PHP/HTML. I don't mind if the whole page reloads. I'm thinking I have to update the POST var on the checkbox click so then when the page reloads, it knows which query to choose.

Comment: Yes, you have to wait for the form to be submitted, and then do the `if` in the script that processes the form data.

Comment: Is there a way to have the checkbox itself reload the page with the different query?

Comment: Only with JavaScript.